# why always error states"Movie instance has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url'

Tags: python-2.7

#### create a class of Movie and post it a webpage using fresh_tomatoes

```
import webbrowser
import fresh_tomatoes
```

#### define a class called Movie

```
class Movie():
    def __init__(self,movie_title, storyline,poster_image,trailer_youtube_url):
        self.movie_title=movie_title
        self.storyline=storyline
        self.poster_image=poster_image
        self.trailer__youtube_url=trailer_youtube_url
    ###define a trailer opening method    
    def show_trailer(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer__youtube_url)


### create an instance of movies, toy_story
toy_story=Movie('Toy Story', 'A boy and his toy',  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYz2wyBy3kc"###url of youtube trailer)
fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(toy_story)
```

Comment: AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url'

Comment: What does `fresh_tomatoes` module do? On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: I down load the fresh_tomatoes at "https://github.com/adarsh0806/ud036_StarterCode/blob/master/fresh_tomatoes.py", which is a module to generate url like to html webpage.

Comment: the error shows "line 157, in open_movies_page" and line 136, in create_movie_tiles_content
    r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url'

Comment: Try removing the double underscore in from the attribute variable `self.trailer__youtube_url`. Just make it `trailer_youtube_url`.

Comment: You are right, My carelessness kills it. thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't worry. It happens to the best of us. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem.

```
self.trailer__youtube_url
```

should be:

```
self.trailer_youtube_url
```

Just delete the extra underscore and it should work.